# How do you expand a form at runtime in VB.NET to display more information?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form in VB.NET and I would like the user to be able to click a button which will display another form (with the original form still visible).

How do I do this?

Comment: Is this windows or web application?

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyButton.Click

    Dim MySecondForm As New MySecondFormType()
    MySecondForm.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can control where the second form shows up?

Comment: @RobinReborn Use `StartPosition`, `Location`, and `Size` properties of the form. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dza70hfb.aspx.